# How to select multiple rows by their composite primary keys in JOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, select, jooq, composite-primary-key

I have a table with composite primary key. I want to find rows with some set of primary keys.

My table is:

```
create table test_tbl
(
    id_part_1 varchar(36) not null,
    id_part_2 varchar(36) not null,
    some_data text not null,
    constraint test_tbl_pkey
        primary key (id_part_1, id_part_2)
);
```

My `SQL` query is:

```
SELECT * FROM test_tbl
    WHERE (id_part_1, id_part_2) IN (('id_part_1_1', 'id_part_2_1'), ('id_part_1_2', 'id_part_2_2'));
```

So, how to implement this query with help of JOOQ? I don't generate JOOQ Dao, I just have JOOQ tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to do this manually

You can translate your SQL query directly to jOOQ using [`DSL.row()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row(org.jooq.Field,org.jooq.Field)) to construct a row value expression, and then:

```
row(TEST_TBL.ID_PART_1, TEST_TBL.ID_PART_2).in(
  row("id_part_1_1", "id_part_2_1"),
  row("id_part_1_2", "id_part_2_2")
);
```

See also the [jOOQ manual section about the `IN` predicate, degree > 1](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/)

#### Use embeddable keys

Alternatively, you can profit from the additional type safety offered by the new jOOQ 3.14 [`<embeddablePrimaryKeys/>`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-embeddable-types/codegen-embedded-keys/) feature, which allows you to generate record types for all primary keys and their referencing foreign keys. Your query would then read:

```java
ctx.select()
   .from(TEST_TBL)
   .where(TEST_TBL.TEST_TBL_PKEY.in(
      new TestTblPkeyRecord("id_part_1_1", "id_part_2_1"),
      new TestTblPkeyRecord("id_part_1_2", "id_part_2_2")
   ))
   .fetch();
```

This produces the same query as your original one, but does so type safely, and you'll never forget a key column again. Not only when you query the primary key, but also when you join it! Changing the key will result in a compilation error:

```java
ctx.select()
   .from(TEST_TBL)
   .join(OTHER_TEST_TBL)
   .on(TEST_TBL.TEST_TBL_PKEY.eq(OTHER_TEST_TBL.TEST_TBL_PKEY.TEST_TBL_FKEY))
   .fetch();
```

Or an [implicit join](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) would look like this:

```java
ctx.select(OTHER_TEST_TBL.testTbl().fields(), OTHER_TEST_TBL.fields())
   .from(OTHER_TEST_TBL)
   .fetch();
```